# Deleting files from s3 of 0 bytes

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awk, aws-cli

Is there a way to delete files of 0bytes from amazon s3 bucket.
I am currently trying out

> aws s3 ls s3//bucket  --recursive --profile ***** | awk '{ seq_no = $3; if ( seq_no == 0) print "rm s3://bucket/" $4; }' | sh

but this does not work.

Is there any other way to do this

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `| sh`.  Examine what is being generated.

Comment: There should be a `:` after s3 link as `s3://bucket

Answer (score 1):

You may use :

`s3cmd ls --recursive s3://BUCKET_NAME | ruby -rdate -ne 'date, time, size, uri = $_.split; puts uri if size == "0"' | xargs s3cmd del`

if you don't have `s3cmd` installed, `aws s3 ls` works as well.

Reference: https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/4551494

**UPDATE :**

To be exact

`` for filename in `aws s3 ls --recursive s3://$BUCKETNAME/$FOLDERLOCATION/| ruby -rdate -ne 'date, time, size, uri = $_.split; puts uri if size == "0"'`
do
aws s3 rm s3://$BUCKETNAME/$filename
done ``

this worked for me.

Comment: were you able to give it a try?